# Multithreading benchmark test

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking, synchronized

I want to measure how long it takes for the 2 threads to count till 1000. How can I make a benchmark test of the following code?

```
public class Main extends Thread {
    public static int number = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Main();
        Thread t2 = new Main();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            increment();
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " " + getNumber());
        }
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        number++;
    }

    public synchronized int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

And why am I still getting the following result (extract) even though I use the `synchronized` keyword?

```
Thread-0 9
Thread-0 11
Thread-0 12
Thread-0 13
Thread-1 10
```

Comment: Java code doesn't warm up until it has been run 10,000 times.  I would ignore at least the first 10K times.

Comment: You synchronize accesses to `number`, however this does not make `println()` atomic. In fact, the count may even have been incremented before you `.getNumber()`.

Comment: Not to mention that adding from 0 to 1000 will require a so small time that the typical overhead/variation due external factors will probably make the values meaningless. Do not only get the mean values, check that they all are in the same range.

Comment: See my answer, it covers all your synchronization problems

Comment: Like @SJuan76 syas, almost every other line of your program will take longer than counting to 1000.  Try 10000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not synchronized. The `synchronized` keyword is an equivalent to `synchonize (this) {}` but you are increasing a `static` number which is not contained within your object. You actually have 2 objects/threads and both of them synchronize with themself, not with each other.

Either make you property `volatile` and don't synchronize at all or use a lock Object like this:

```
public static int number = 0;
public static final Object lock = new Object();

public void increment() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        number++;
    }
}

public int getNumber() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not change the fact that printing may happen in different orders.

Comment: You are right. The problem was, that my threads weren't interacting witch each other.

Answer (score 1):

Output is not synchronized. The scenario is:

1. Thread-0 runs 9 iterations alone.
2. Thread-1 calls increment and getNumber, which returns `10`.
3. Thread-0 runs three more iterations.
4. Thread-1 calls println with `10`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not synchronizing this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        increment();
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " " + getNumber());
    }
```

So, a thread can execute `increment()`, wait for the next thread, and after that keep with `getValue()` (thus getting your results). Given how fast is adding a value, changing a thread gives the other time for several iterations.

Do
    public static final String LOCK = "lock";

```
synchronized(LOCK) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        increment();
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " " + getNumber());
    }
}
```

you do not need the `synchronize` for the methods (as I explain in my comment).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Dumb me. `synchronized` methods are the same than `synchronize(this)` and both lock using the object itself. As you have two thread, each of them synchronizes by its object so they don't interfere. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> why am I still getting the following result (extract) even though I use the synchronized keyword?

You synchronize access to the `number` variable, however the increment and get are synchronized separately, and this does not make your `println()` atomic either. This sequence is perfectly possible:

```
0 -> inc
1 -> inc
0 -> getnumber
1 -> getnumber
1 -> print
0 -> print
```

First, if you want to solve the "increment and get" problem, you can use an `AtomicInteger`:

```
private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

// ...

@Override
public void run()
{
    final String me = getName();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        System.out.println(me + ": " + count.incrementAndGet());
}
```

However, even this will not guarantee printing order. With the code above, this scenario is still possible:

```
0 -> inc
0 -> getnumber
1 -> inc
1 -> getnumber
1 -> print
0 -> print
```

To solve this problem, you need to use, for instance, a `ReentrantLock`:

```
private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private static int count;

// ...

@Override
public void run()
{
    final String me = getName;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // ALWAYS lock() in front of a try block and unlock() in finally
        lock.lock();
        try {
            count++;
            System.out.println(me + ": " + count);
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```